# CSS margin issue - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

Good morning gentlemans.

I´m currently having a little bit of an issue and because I´ve been stuck on this for hour, I wanted to give it a shot here and ask wiser and more experienced people than I´m.

I´m working on site - https://canal.predajweb.sk/ and my issue is that #page .page-container is getting margin-top as an element.style. I´ve read something about collapsing margins and I´ve been looking for a solution, but without any succcess. My main issue is that I don´t know where is that margin from (from where that container gets that margin)

I believe its going to have some simple solution, but as I´m quite new to this, I don´t know what to look for.

Thanks very much for kind advices and have a great day!
Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its like an jQuery or Javascript problem,
Anyway if you want to have a specific margins set :

```
#page {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

Otherwise you need to check your scripts and css files for any unwanted code.

jQuery Solution:

```
jQuery('#page').css('margin-top','0');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `#page div` has inline CSS.

[image: Inline css]

**EDIT**

The code that determines the `height` is defined in the init.min.js file

```js
if (ThGlobal.is_fixed_header == 1) {
            if (jQuery(".main-slider-container").length > 0) {
                jQuery(".main-slider-container").css({
                    "margin-top": jQuery(".head-container").outerHeight() + 10
                })
            } else {
                jQuery("#page").css({
                    "margin-top": jQuery(".head-container").outerHeight()
                })
            }
        } else {
            jQuery("#page").css({
                "margin-top": 0
            })
        }
```

You can either change this or create your own height, the most simple way is probably overriding the CSS like the other answer

Comment: Bad answer. if you change the browser or screen width and refresh the page you can see that the value for margin-top is changed, which is easy to tell, its a javascript or jquery function for slider or so. Vote down sorry.